# How to efficiently SQL select newest entries from a MySQL database?

Tags: sql, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Query to get latest price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404/sql-query-to-get-latest-price)

I have a database containing stock price history. I want to select most recent prices for every stock that is listed. I know PostreSQL has a [DISTINCT ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224/joining-latest-of-various-usermetadata-tags-to-user-rows#27159) statement that would suit ideally here.

Table columns are `name`, `closingPrice` and `date`; `name` and `date` together form a unique index.

The *easiest* (and very uneffective) way is

```
SELECT * FROM stockPrices s
WHERE s.date =
(SELECT MAX(date) FROM stockPrices si WHERE si.name = s.name);
```

Much better approach I found is

```
SELECT *
FROM stockPrices s JOIN (
  SELECT name, MAX(date) AS date
  FROM stockPrices si
  GROUP BY name
) lastEntry ON s.name = lastEntry.name AND s.date = lastEntry.date;
```

What would be an efficient way to do this? What indexes should I create?

> duplicate of:
>   [SQL Query to get latest price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404/sql-query-to-get-latest-price)

Comment: See [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404/sql-query-to-get-latest-price)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your second approach is very efficient. What's its problem?

You have to add indexes to name and date.

Comment: Well, you have to add an index if performance requires it. If it's ten stocks and a year's daily data, I wouldn't be concerned: MySQL is relatively good at table scanning.

Comment: If he had few data he wouldn't be asking for an efficient way to do this, no? Even the first, obvious approach would be enough.